Trying to reshape a a data frame into long form
I have a dataset with 4 columns, a product description and 3 years (1996, 2007, 2020).
I want to change the table into the long format making so that it has 3 columns: Product, Year and the value that was under the given year in the original dataset.
Here's the dataset:

! structure(list(Product = c("Soft wheat", "Durum wheat", "Rye",
"Barley", "Oat", "Maize", "Sorghum", "Triticale", "Other cereals",
"Total cereals"), 1996 = c(3.6616684588, NA, 2.64103083700441,
2.814404478, 2.399888609, 5.1972385322, NA, NA, 3.4615, 4.36583009052598
), 2007 = c(5.21289336717319, 4.8786599019381, 2.46478612716763,
3.78568144067797, 1.98542545584555, 4.91636347253509, NA, 3.45350553505535,
2.73019718309859, 4.7024162704803), 2020 = c(5.76343534131085,
4.17933552631579, 4.03194339622642, 4.80996336499322, 3.33150257731959,
8.39248085991678, NA, 4.16039316239316, 1.72273076923077, 6.92400090523919
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

I tried doing this
reshape(croatia_yield, 
        direction = "long",
        varying = c("1996", "2007", "2020"),
        v.names = "Value",
        timevar = "Year",
        times = c("1996", "2007", "2020"),
        new.row.names = 1:30)

but I keep getting this error
Error in `[<-`:
! Assigned data `ids` must be compatible with existing data.
✖ Existing data has 30 rows.
✖ Assigned data has 10 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Caused by error in `vectbl_recycle_rhs_rows()`:
! Can't recycle input of size 10 to size 30.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I don't know what's going on, if anyone could help it would be apreciated. Also I can't use any other libraries, so I would need a base R solution.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Does it work if you do croatia_yield = as.data.frame(croatia_yield) first?

Yes, that fixed it! Thank you!
